# Asynchronous Execution of arbitrary operations using Tasks

Tags: c#

I have a set of arbitrary operations which I want to execute using the Task Parallel Library. I dont want to spin off a new background thread by using Task.Factory.StartNew.

How do I execute any arbitrary operation asynchronously using the Tasks framework? To use Task.Factory.FromAsync, the operations need to expose Begin and End methods.

Any guidance on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Factory.StartNew()` does **not** imply that you are starting a *new* background thread. Instead the TPL is using a thread pool from which it can pick one once a thread is available to execute the delegate / method you pass.

So yes that method will be executed asynchronously and will not cause a new thread to be started. Exactly when the delegate is executed depends on the scheduling algorithm in the TPL and how many competing threads are already running, in general the TPL will try and use all the processors that are available on a machine.

Comment: Yes, I understand it uses a thread from the thread pool. What I want is, I want to execute some arbitrary operation on the same thread asynchronously instead of using a thread from the thread pool.  When I call BeginInvoke on a delegate, this executes on the same thread, but asynchronously. I want to achieve similar functionality but with Tasks.

Comment: BeginInvoke on a delegate actually uses a thead pool thread for execution of the operation. It does not use the same thread as the caller.

Comment: Hmm...this is what I am trying to solve. I have to implement a WCF service operation which calls another WCF service and database and do some intensive processing. If I use the Task.Factory.StartNew() this uses a thread from the threadpool, but when an IO request is made, say to another WCF service, the thread pool thread is blocked. If my understanding is correct, how do I write this so that the WCF threads are not blocked while waiting for IO.

Comment: @dotnetlearner: You cannot execute an operation asynchronously on the same thread. Asynchronously just means that it is not in the current thread. When you want to run it on the same thread, just call the method you want. But then it is synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can run asynchronous operations on one thread using async/await. The thread needs to have

```
 System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current != null
```

otherwise threadpool threads are used!
You will have a sync context (with message queue) when using threads from e.g. WinForms, WPF or Nito.Async.ActionThread.
See [threadsafety and the message queue](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/asyncwcflib/index.php?title=Threadsafety_and_the_message_queue).
Use [AsyncWcfLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asyncwcflib) for WCF services calling other WCF services.